# PyCharm жалуется на Unresolved reference 'cursor'

Tags: telegram-bot, sqlite, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

[image: Скрин ошибки]Сам код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def search_message(message):
    sch = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите параметры поиска (id, юзер)')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sch, process_search_step)


def process_search_step(message):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM id, username WHERE userscod = %s"
    query = message.text
    cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for x in result:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, x)
```

Comment: И правильно жалуется, в функции переменная cursor не объявлена. Ее надо либо передать в функцию аргументом(если ранее объявлена - похоже на соединение с бд), либо создать в функции, либо, если cursor глобальная переменная, доставать ее через ключевое слово global

Comment: Вам нужно более чётко излагать проблему. Указывать не просто отрывок из кода и скрин ошибок, но и тщательно описывать что вы хотели сделать и что вы пробовали.

Answer (score 0):

как и сказали выше, переменнная не обьявлена, нужно установить соединение между открытой бд и курсором, если соединение установлено раньше, то просто обьявить переменную глобальной

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).